Flutter InAppWebView Build Issue: Execution failed for task 'flutter_inappwebview
I'm encountering an issue with my Flutter app and could really use some assistance. Here are the details:
Problem:
I'm facing a build failure with the following error message:
ERROR: Missing classes detected while running R8. Please add the missing classes or apply additional keep rules that are generated in D:home_page_design\build\flutter_inappwebview\outputs\mapping\release\missing_rules.txt.
ERROR: R8: Missing class android.window.BackEvent (referenced from: void io.flutter.view.FlutterView.startBackGesture(android.window.BackEvent) and 1 other context)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_inappwebview:minifyReleaseWithR8'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.R8Task$R8Runnable
   > Compilation failed to complete

Additional Details:
This error occurs during the execution of assembleRelease in Gradle.
I've tried running with --stacktrace but need help interpreting the output.
Steps I've Taken:
Updated Flutter and all dependencies.
Cleaned and rebuilt the project.
Verified all configurations are correct.
What I'm Seeking:
Any insights into what might be causing this issue?
Suggestions on how to resolve or further diagnose the problem?
Has anyone encountered a similar issue with Flutter InAppWebView and found a solution?

Can you share your pubspec.yaml file?

Since you have not provided your pubspec.yaml file so I can only assume you are using one of the latest version of Flutter and also of flutter flutter_inappwebview.
There is an issue open on flutter_inappwebview's repository which seems very similar to the one you have posted.
There are several suggestions there on how to resolve it.
The last comment there, suggests to add this line at the beginning of the build.gradle file:
project.gradle.startParameter.excludedTaskNames.add(":flutter_inappwebview:minifyReleaseWithR8")


Here is code of pubspec.yaml file
environment:
sdk: '>=3.2.3 <4.0.0'
dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
get: ^4.6.6
get_storage: ^2.1.1
flutter_screenutil: ^5.9.0
carousel_slider: ^4.2.1
form_field_validator: ^1.1.0
curved_navigation_bar: ^1.0.3
expansion_tile_card: ^3.0.0
image_picker: ^1.0.7
dropdown_button2: ^2.3.7
material_tag_editor: ^0.1.2
.
choice: ^2.3.0
google_sign_in: ^6.2.1
.
http: ^1.2.0

another_flushbar: ^1.12.30
For get fcm token.
firebase_messaging: ^14.7.15
firebase_core: ^2.28.0
For using date variable.
intl: ^0.19.0
For using mesibo chat.
mesibo_flutter_sdk: ^2.2.5
For using live agent chat.
#flutter_tawk: ^0.1.0
flutter_tawkto: ^0.0.3
For handling the otp field.
pinput: ^4.0.0
For the toast msg use.
fluttertoast: ^8.2.5
For use the lunch URL.
url_launcher: ^6.2.6

dev_dependencies:
flutter_test:
sdk: flutter
flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
assets:
- assets/images/
fonts:
- family: Exo2
fonts:
- asset: assets/fonts/Exo2-Regular.ttf
- family: Roboto
fonts:
- asset: assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf

@PiyushSahu - Please edit your question to include the pubspec.yaml file contents in it instead of adding several comments to the answer. Also, if my answer helped you, please mark it as such.
